# How to call redis-cli from Grunt?

Tags: javascript, shell, command-line, gruntjs, command

I'm trying to call redis-cli from Grunt. The reason is I want to be able to easily connect to the various instance or Redis we have without having to check or remember the connection details. E.g. I want to call `grunt redis-cli:staging` to run redis-cli against the Redis DB of our staging environment.

I had success calling other redis utility (i.e. redis-stat, redis-commander) using the [grunt-run module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run). However, when I try with redis-cli it does not work.

I suspect it is due to the type of utility. redis-cli is a prompt to run redis commands while the others are just tools that does not expect user inputs.

Any idea how I could start redis-cli (ideally synchronously) from Grunt?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** Fixed typos and clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just make a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
redis-cli -h staging -p 1234
```

Name it `dbstage` then you run with `./dbstage`